# How to pick up liferay radio button value using jQuery

Tags: jquery, liferay-6

I am using two radio buttons for my application which shows employed and unemployed status .Now i have to pick up the values using jQuery.So what i have tried is here

```
<tr>
                <th>Current Employment status<span style='color: #FF0000; display: inline;'>*</span></th>
                <td>
                    <c:choose>
                        <c:when test='<%= employmentStatus.equals("Employed") %>'>
                            <aui:input checked="<%=true%>" inlineField="true" label="Employed" value="Employed" type="radio" name="employmentStatus" id="employed"></aui:input>
                            <aui:input inlineField="true" label="Not Employed" value="Not Employed" type="radio" name="employmentStatus" id="notEmployed"></aui:input>
                        </c:when>
                        <c:when test='<%= employmentStatus.equals("Not Employed") %>'>
                            <aui:input inlineField="true" label="Employed" value="Employed" type="radio" name="employmentStatus" id="employed"></aui:input>
                            <aui:input checked="<%=true%>" inlineField="true" label="Not Employed" value="Not Employed" type="radio" name="employmentStatus" id="notEmployed"></aui:input>
                        </c:when>
                        <c:when test='<%= employmentStatus.equals("") %>'>
                            <aui:input checked="<%=true%>" inlineField="true" label="Employed" value="Employed" type="radio" name="employmentStatus" id="employed"></aui:input>
                            <aui:input inlineField="true" label="Not Employed" value="Not Employed" type="radio" name="employmentStatus" id="notEmployed"></aui:input>
                        </c:when>
                    </c:choose> 
                </td>
            </tr>
```

And this is the way i am picking up the radio button value.

```
employementStatus=$('#<portlet:namespace/>employed').val();
```

But i am not able to pick up the value ,somebody please help

Comment: You need to use a jQuery selector based on the HTML that the liferay library outputs. Check the HTML in a DOM inspector to find out exactly what elements you need to target.

Comment: `.val()` is different than the attribute `value`.   `.val()` is used for getting a user-entered value from a text input, text area, or select.  You most likely want something like `.attr('value')`  more here: http://api.jquery.com/attr/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a liferay developer, but given the expected rendered HTML, your jQuery could be `$(input[name="employmentStatus"]:checked).val()`, which breaks down in this way:

1. get me all `input` elements
2. limit those inputs to the ones that have a `name` attribute of "employmentStatus"
3. further limit to ones that are [`:checked`](https://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/)
4. Get the value of that input using the [`val()`](https://api.jquery.com/val/) method

So, if your HTML looks like this:

```
<input checked="true" value="Employed" type="radio" name="employmentStatus" id="employed" />
<input value="Not Employed" type="radio" name="employmentStatus" id="notEmployed" />
```

`employementStatus=$(input[name="employmentStatus"]:checked).val()` would set `employementStatus` to the string "Employed".

Comment: Does your HTML look like mine (`<input checked="true" value="Employed" type="radio"`...)?

Comment: @lucifer still there?

Comment: No it did not worked i tried normal html radio button to pick values

Comment: What does your resulting HTML look like? Can you add that to your question?

Answer (score 0):

This code might help:

```
$('input[name="<portlet:namespace/>employmentStatus"]:checked').val();
```

Comment: You might want to put you code in a code block, for better readability :)